# Add custom/named properties to MQ message in IIB message flow

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus

I'm new to IIB 9.0 and I've been googling around but I wasn't able to find a good solution on how to add a custom/named property to a MQ message in IIB 9.0 message flow.

In IBM Integration Toolkit, there are two header nodes that can be used in designing a message flow, JMSHeader and MQHeader. The JMSHeader allows me to add new custom (application) properties to the JMS message with no issues. However, the MQHeader, doesn't seems to have the same functionality. I have no issues adding a named property to an MQ message using the sample program, amqsstm, that comes with MQ installation.

AIX/Unix: $MQ_HOME/samp/bin/amqsbcg / amqsstm

Windows: $MQ_HOME\tools\c\Samples\Bin\amqsbcg.exe / amqsstm.exe

In theory, it's probably possible that I can transform the MQ into JMS message then use JMSHeader to add the custom property (using application properties option) then convert it back. But there got to be a better solution than this.

Thanks,

Ron

Answer (score 0):

The message properties are stored in the RFH2 header:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q104190_.htm

> For example, when a IBM WebSphere MQ application attempts to access
>   the Property1 property, this maps to the Property1 element in the
>   usr folder. The wmq.Property2 property maps to the Property2
>   property in the wmq folder.

So I'd try setting them using ESQL:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac16910_.htm